# AtomicInteger set method is Atomic?

Tags: java

Why in `AtomicInteger`or another Atomic class has define this set method?

**example code:**

```
 /**
 * Sets to the given value.
 *
 * @param newValue the new value
 */
public final void set(int newValue) {
    value = newValue;
}
```

**or**

```
/**
 * Sets to the given value.
 *
 * @param newValue the new value
 */
public final void set(V newValue) {
    value = newValue;
}
```

this method not annotation  **atomic** ?this `set()` method is mean he is not atomic yet?

i don't understand why in AtomicInteger or another Atomic (for example:AtomicReference) have no atomic method?
thanks!

Comment: Correct me here, but aren't only variables marked as `@atomic`?

Comment: because assignment in itself is atomic. The key of the `Atomic...` classes is that the field that holds the value is `volatile`.

Comment: It's already atomic. The reason `getAndSet(V)` has "Atomically" in comment is that `get` and `set` both are atomic itself but not still atomic when combining them together, which is a two-step operation.

So there is a method called `getAndSet(V)` combine these two steps together and makes it atomic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A write to or a read from a variable is an atomic operation per se - with the little exception of `long`s and `double`s (see [JLS §17.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7)).

Besides that the `value` field is declared as `volatile`, which makes getting and setting the value thread-safe because "the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable" (see [JLS §8.3.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4)). Additionally, there is also a *happens-before* relationship when dealing with volatile variables (see [JLS §17.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)).

This means that the methods `get` and `set` are atomic operations per se without any further synchronizing mechanism. Other operations - such as `getAndSet` or `compareAndSet` - must use some further synchronization mechanisms to ensure atomicity.

Answer (score 0):

Because `AtomicInteger` provides additional methods like [`public final int getAndSet(int newValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndSet-int-) for operations that must be atomic.

Comment: Why are non-atomic methods available in atomic classes? This lead us to think that the set() method is the atomic method. i'm very troubled.beside, at my first glance,I think  this `set(T value)` is  atomic method.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is , per-se, automic, as it has only one instruction. So there is no need for any synchronization, unlike the other methods like `getAndSet`, for which too the documentation says that they have been ensured to work atomically .

Comment: CompareAndSet (), should be we need to get the previous value, and then do some calculation or business process,then  set value so we need to use this method compareAndSet (), and set () should be our direct assignment, without first obtaining the original value of the operation    canI understand so?

Comment: Nope, its actually `Atomically sets the value to the given updated value if the current value == the expected value.` See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#compareAndSet-int-int-

Comment: The `set` method is the normal setter method found in POJOs, I guess it'd have been better if they had made it `immutable` :)